# How do you add a vm as a hard drive?

Tags: virtualbox

I was wonder how do you add a virtual machine (using virtual box) as if you added a hard drive? I am pretty sure you can do that in windows, I just do not know how to do that in Ubuntu.

Comment: What does it mean "add a virtual machine as if you added a hard drive"? That seems unclear.

Comment: I mean like you know how you add a external hard drive in Ubuntu it will show it to you in the Disk menu? I would like to manage my VM like I would manage a operating system. (I dual-booted Ubuntu with Windows, so from Ubuntu I can see Windows.)

Comment: You mean you want the VM's disk be accessible by the host OS? Basically that should not be possible, because with VM the two OSes are running **simultaneously** (unlike with dual boot) and the one does not know about the other, and simultaneous disk writes from two OSes are likely to damage the data on disk. However, there probably is some method to **share** your VM disk (from inside VM) over the internal network to the host OS and access it on the host OS in the way like you access **network drives**.

Comment: Yeah, I would like that. I am a noob at Ubuntu, would you mind explaining to me how to do that?

Comment: @ACTS238 That's going to depend on the operating system that you have running in the VM.  I don't think VirtualBox on Windows behaves any differently in this respect.

Comment: What OS does your VM run? You have to share the network drive using the method appropriate for that OS. A VM is just like another computer running in parallel with your main OS, so just google for any description of how to share drives over a network from one computer to another. Of course, you need first to have network connection working on your VM.

Comment: I have Windows 7 on my VM.

Comment: So try to share the drive as you would normally share it over the network in Windows, and then try to find it under "Windows network" in Ubuntu file manager. You have to work out the details.

Comment: I tried making a shared folder, but that did not work. Any ideas why?

Comment: This sounds like a Windows problem more than an Ubuntu one. Make sure you’re using the correct network adapter type on the VM, too.

Comment: You can copy/paste from your physical HDD to your virtual HDD. Is that not good enough?